# I am not unable to get the multi select box using angularJS and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, visualforce, bootstrap-multiselect

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WM1Z.png)   I tried to get the multiselect box for the state field as i shown in figure but I am not able to get the multiselect box eventhough i included all bootstrap multi select , angularjs ,bootstrap css .And see the image . Please give any suggestion to complete this task

```
 <div  ng-if="productItem.APTS_Dis== '1' ">                                                                      
       <select multi-select="multi-select" multiple="multiple"
    ng-model="productItem[productItem.Name]" 
    ng-change="onStateChangeDD(productItem[productItem.Name],key, productItem)"
     ng-options="ddItem.Name as removeAmparsendFilter(ddItem.Name) for ddItem in productItem.ddData | orderBy:'Name'">
     </select> 
    </div>
```

Comment: did you test that your multiselect is working in the most basic scenario to be sure that your references are correct? ex  https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: its working for the static data ... but its not working for the dynamic data .  I used all plugins what required for the multi select .